# Wordpress Login redirection issue

Tags: wordpress, authentication, redirect

After successful login from wp-login page, unfortunately it was redirecting to homepage instead of dashboard. Can anyone help  me for this type issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)